# Programa divisor de un numero en java

Tags: java

Estoy intentando hacer un ejercicio de clase, soy novato en java y este es mi segunda tarea.

El enunciado es este:

Realiza un programa en Java que pida al usuario un número entero. Tras procesarlo, el programa informa de si el número es divisible por 2 o no lo es

He hecho esto, pero al  meterle por ejemplo 2 o 1 dice que no es divisor, haber si me podéis echar una mano de lo que falla:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class operador_interrogante {


  public static void main(String[] args) {

      int num;
      byte divisor = 2;
      int division;

      Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Introduce un numero entero");
      num = teclado.nextInt();

      division = num/=divisor;

      if (divisor == division){
      System.out.println("Son divisores");
      }else{
      System.out.println("No son divisores");
      }

  }
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para saber si un numero es divisible entre otro es mejor usar la operación modulo `%` y comprobar que el resultado es 0.

```
if(num%2==0){
    System.out.println("Son divisores");
}else{
    System.out.println("No son divisores");
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias JDev!

Answer (score 0):

El fallo que estás teniendo es que estás comparando el resultado de la división con el divisor. Es decir, si tu pones un 2 estás comparando el resultado de 2/2, que es 1, con el divisor, que es 2. Así siempre  te va a devolver false a no ser que por casualidad el resultado de una división sea igual que el divisor. Por ejemplo 4/2=2, 2==2.

Como te han dicho arriba lo mejor es que utilices %(modulo) para comprobar si un numero es divisible entre 2.